# Why do we have to scrape the inside of the cheek twice to get the sample of epithelial cells?

Tags: microscopy

I was studying the theory of a practical exercise of preparing temporary slide of animal tissue from my [laboratory manual](https://ncert.nic.in/pdf/publication/sciencelaboratorymanuals/classXI/biology/kelm305.pdf).

In the section about epithelial tissue, the first few steps of the procedure contains the following.

> • Rinse your mouth well with water.
> • Gently scrape the inside of your cheek with the broad end of a clean
> toothpick. Discard this material.
> • Scrape again, and spread these cells gently on a clean slide. Add a drop
> of 0.9% NaCl solution or physiological saline and a drop of methylene
> blue with the help of a dropper.

Why is it mentioned to scrape and discard the first time and scrape again?

I've tried searching about it on the web but couldn't find any mention of scraping twice to obtain the sample, nor it is mentioned in my book. There doesn't seem to be any apparent reason to scrape twice to me.

Comment: What do you think? What have you found in your research? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Unresearched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) for more information.

Comment: @MattDMo I've added info. accordingly.